# how to update npm package, no new version

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm maintaining a npm package for which I received a GitHub dependabot security alert for one of it's dependencies. I accepted the gh bot proposal which ended up in a `gh pull request` with an updated `package-lock.json`. I checked out the pr branch locally and run my tests against it. It is all ok and I want to merge it into master. But how do I publish the new package, do I have to create a new version or is it best practice to crate a new npm version? Because nothing else changed (only one dependency) can I just update the package without creating a new version? Thanks for your thoughts.

I read the npm documentation, but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can try this in your terminal and will update the npm version. I think this would be helpful.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-version

commands: this will update to the latest version.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: i dont have have a problem with npm, i have a problem with my own npm package